# Leetcode Compiler error of the control reaching end of non-void function

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, multidimensional-array, compiler-errors

I am a newbie programmer, trying to go through questions on leetcode. I understand the logic, I know how the main function is in the back end of leetcode & about returning in a particular instructed way. But every time I write a code it throws a compiler error about the control reaching end of non-void function and I can't seem to figure out how to counter this error. Please help me out.

The code I have written and have been trying to run on leetcode (It is the problem 74: Search a 2-D matrix):

```
bool searchMatrix(int** matrix, int matrixSize, int* matrixColSize, int target){
    int x;
    for(int i=0;i<matrixSize;i++){
        if(target<=matrix[i][*matrixColSize-1])
           x=i;
    }
    if(target>matrix[matrixSize-1][*matrixColSize-1])
           return false;
    for(int j=0;j<*matrixColSize;j++){
        if(matrix[x][j]==target)
            return true;
        if(j==*matrixColSize-1 && matrix[x][j]!=target)
            return false;
    }
}
```

I can't seem to find what is wrong with the code. Even if I try to move the return command out of if loop, it just keeps returning false for every

Comment: If none of the `if` conditions are true, you will exit the `for` loop without returning a boolean.

Answer (score 2):

If `*matrixColSize` is 0 (or worse, negative) the `for` loop will never execute, and you'll fall through to the end of the function without executing one of the `return` statements.

Even if the loop does execute, checking every time to see if it's the last iteration is a confusing way to write the function. Just let it finish the loop, and if it hasn't found a match, there's no match, so you can return `false` by default.

```
    for(int j=0;j<*matrixColSize;j++){
        if(matrix[x][j]==target)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
```

Comment: Re “The compiler is not able to figure out that on the last iteration of the `for` loop”: The body of the `for` loop might never execute; `*matrixColSize` may be zero or negative. (That would make `*matrixColSize-1` negative, but the compiler cannot deduce that has undefined behavior because `matrix[i]` could point into the middle of an array, so a negative subscript on it would be defined.)

Comment: @EricPostpischil Facepalm! I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

After executing this for loop

```
for(int j=0;j<*matrixColSize;j++){
    if(matrix[x][j]==target)
        return true;
    if(j==*matrixColSize-1 && matrix[x][j]!=target)
        return false;
}
```

the function returns nothing. You need to place a return statement after the for loop.

Or you need to rewrite the loop such a way that the result would be returned after the loop.

For example there could be used while loop as

```
int j = 0;

while ( j < *matrixColSize && matrix[x][j] != target ) ++j;

return j != *matrixColSize;
```

Also it is unclear why the third parameter has pointer type

```
int* matrixColSize
```

Pay attention to that in C you can use variable length arrays that could be used instead of dynamically allocated arrays.

Another remark is that instead of this for loop

```
for(int i=0;i<matrixSize;i++){
    if(target<=matrix[i][*matrixColSize-1])
       x=i;
}
```

that searches the rows sequantially you could implement the binary search methid as the upper bound method because accirding to the description of the task each first element of the row is greater than the last element of the previous row. And then for the selected row you could use standard C function `bsearch`.

Here is a C++ program shown as a pseudo-code that demonstrates ideas how the function can be implemented based on the binary search method applied to rows of the matrix and then to the selected row.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

bool searchMatrix( const std::vector<std::vector<int>> &matrix, int target )
{
    std::vector<int> value = { target };

    auto row = std::upper_bound( std::begin( matrix ), std::end( matrix ), value,
        []( const auto &row1, const auto &row2 ) { return row1[0] < row2[0]; } );

    bool success = row != std::begin( matrix );

    if (success)
    {
        std::advance( row, -1 );

        size_t size = row->size();

        success = !( ( *row )[size - 1] < target ) &&
            std::binary_search( std::begin( *row ), std::end( *row ), target );
    }

    return success;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> matrix =
    {
        {  1,  3,  5,  7 },
        { 10, 11, 16, 20 },
        { 23, 30, 34, 60 }
    };

    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    std::cout << "searchMatrix( matrix, 0 )  is " << searchMatrix( matrix, 0 )  << '\n';
    std::cout << "searchMatrix( matrix, 8 )  is " << searchMatrix( matrix, 8 )  << '\n';
    std::cout << "searchMatrix( matrix, 3 )  is " << searchMatrix( matrix, 3 )  << '\n';
    std::cout << "searchMatrix( matrix, 13 ) is " << searchMatrix( matrix, 13 ) << '\n';
    std::cout << "searchMatrix( matrix, 60 ) is " << searchMatrix( matrix, 60 ) << '\n';
    std::cout << "searchMatrix( matrix, 61 ) is " << searchMatrix( matrix, 61 ) << '\n';
}
```

The program output is

```
searchMatrix( matrix, 0 )  is false
searchMatrix( matrix, 8 )  is false
searchMatrix( matrix, 3 )  is true
searchMatrix( matrix, 13 ) is false
searchMatrix( matrix, 60 ) is true
searchMatrix( matrix, 61 ) is false
```

That is in your function implementation instead of the first for loop

```
for(int i=0;i<matrixSize;i++){
    if(target<=matrix[i][*matrixColSize-1])
       x=i;
}
```

you should use the binary search method (written by you yourself) to find the target row. In the shown C++ program above it is the standard algorithm `std::upper_bound`.

And then instead of the second for loop you should use standard C function `bsearch` because as it is written in the assignment

> You must write a solution in O(log(m * n)) time complexity.

It is the main requirement of the assignment. That is you shall not use the sequential search within the function.

`Update`. I would write the function in C the following way

```
bool searchMatrix( int **matrix, int matrixSize, int *matrixColSize, int target ) 
{
    bool success = matrixSize > 0 && *matrixColSize > 0;

    if (success)
    {
        int target_row = 0, last_row = matrixSize;

        while (target_row < last_row)
        {
            int middle_row = target_row + ( last_row - target_row ) / 2;

            if (target < matrix[middle_row][0])
            {
                last_row = middle_row;
            }
            else
            {
                target_row = middle_row + 1;
            }
        }

        success = target_row != 0;

        if ( success )
        {
            --target_row;

            success = !( matrix[target_row][*matrixColSize - 1] < target ) &&
                bsearch( &target, matrix[target_row], *matrixColSize, sizeof( int ), cmp ) != NULL;
        }
    }

    return success;
}
```

I used the declaration presented in the site though as I already pointed out there is neither sense to pass the number of columns through a pointer to it.

The function `cmp` can look the following way

```
int cmp( const void *p1, const void *p2 )
{
    int x = *( const int * )p1;
    int y = *( const int * )p2;

    return ( y < x ) - ( x < y );
}
```

Comment: I now realize this is actually a false positive in the compiler warning. On the last iteration of the loop, `j == *matrixColSize-1` is guaranteed to be true, so that `return false` will be executed.

Comment: The arguments and their types are set by the leetcode test engine. Sometimes they're unusual.

Comment: @Barmar You said j==*matrixColSize-1 is guaranteed to be true but I did place && so that both the conditions need to be true.

Comment: Also I did try to replace the return command in for loops by using a variable say int p. I assigned p=0 for true and p=1 for false and then at the end I used if to see if p is 0 or 1 and return true or false as per it

Comment: @rudyxx_07 `matrix[x][j]!=target` is also guaranteed to be true because you just tested the opposite condition on the previous line, and it was false.

Comment: Your other attempt was probably not breaking out of the loop when it set p = 1, so the next iteration replaced it with p = 0, and you returned the wrong result. You have to stop when you find a match.

Comment: A C++ solution to a C question is probably not appropriate.  Avoidance of multiple return points and especially returning from within  loop though is certainly to be encouraged.

Comment: @Clifford The C++ code is presented as a pseudo-code.:)

Comment: Hmm.  Rather more complex perhaps than a self professed _newbie programmer_ might cope with.  Pseudocode is normally a _simplified_ expression using structured natural language understandable by a non-programmer that may easily be implemented in a _real_ programming language. C++ code is not necessarily easily translated to C I'd suggest.  But OK you've made your intent clear.